# struts form loop vs jstl loop

Tags: jsp, jstl, struts-1

I wish to further understand the restrictions of struts forms loop vs jstl loop.

For example I have this iterate loop:

```
<logic:iterate id="displayObj" name="mercurySubscriptionForm" property="displayObjects">
                        <logic:notEqual name="displayObj" property="dataTypeId" value="100">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"></td>
                            <td colspan="3" class="formConf"><bean:write name="displayObj" property="description" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td width="30%" class="formOpt"><bean:write name="displayObj" property="fieldName" />:</td>
                            <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
                            <bean:define id="maxLength" name="displayObj" property="maxLength"/>
                            <%
                                String mxStr = String.valueOf(maxLength);
                            %>

                            <logic:notEqual name="displayObj" property="maxLength" value="-1">
                                <td colspan="3" class="formConf"><html:text name="displayObj" property="value" maxlength="<%= mxStr %>" /></td>
                            </logic:notEqual>
                            <logic:equal name="displayObj" property="maxLength" value="-1">
                                <td colspan="3" class="formConf"><html:text name="displayObj" property="value" maxlength="20"/></td>
                            </logic:equal>

                        </tr>
                    </logic:notEqual></logic:iterate>
```

notice the line:

```
<logic:notEqual name="displayObj" property="dataTypeId" value="100">
```

this works if the dataTypeId can only be 100, and is a singular condition. However there are new restrictions to not display items that are datatype 200 or 300. i tried to implement them within the loop as such:

```
<logic:equal name="displayObj" property="dataTypeId" value="200"></logic:equal>
<logic:equal name="displayObj" property="dataTypeId" value="300"></logic:equal>
```

however this sort of nested logic does not seem to work as struts still spits out the 200 and 300 values, thus I used JSTL instead and it worked well.. however does anyone know why the nested condition logic did not work using struts forms?

Comment: That is the limitation in logic tags. You cannot use multiple conditions in one logic tag.

Comment: This is too much work on the view layer anyway; prepare the data before it hits the view.

Answer (score 0):

You should nest the two tags to create an AND condition:

```
<logic:notEqual name="displayObj" property="dataTypeId" value="200">
    <logic:notEqual name="displayObj" property="dataTypeId" value="300">
          //Code to be displayed here
    </logic:notEqual>
</logic:notEqual>
```

Comment: @OakvilleWork. Then something else is wrong, eg the data isn't what we think it is, or a logic condition isn't correct, etc-the idea itself can't not work.